# Side by side stacked barplots with different colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to create a figure with two stacked barplots side by side where each features a different color scheme. Here is some model code:

```
prob.out = function(lam){
  out1 = dpois(x = 0:3, lambda = lam)
return(c(1-sum(out1), sort(out1)))
}
Prob.out = Vectorize(prob.out, SIMPLIFY = "vector")

synth.data = data.frame(
  year = rep(2019:2021, each = 10) %>% as.character(), 
  small.cat = rep(rep(c("a", "b"), each = 5), times = 3), 
  response.var = round(c(Prob.out(lam = c(1, .7, .9, .6, .8, .5)))*10000,0)
)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = synth.data, aes(small.cat, y = response.var, color = response.var, fill = response.var)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill") + 
  facet_wrap(~year)
```

Is there a way to change the small.cat color scales independently of each other?

I am aiming to get a figure that looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be the `ggnewscale` package which allows for multiple scales for the same aesthetic. To make this work you have to add the bars for each `small.cat` via a separate `geom_col`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

ggplot(data = synth.data, aes(small.cat, y = response.var)) +
  geom_col(data = subset(synth.data, small.cat == "a"), aes(color = response.var, fill = response.var), position = "fill") + 
  new_scale_fill() +
  new_scale_color() +
  geom_col(data = subset(synth.data, small.cat == "b"), aes(color = response.var, fill = response.var), position = "fill") + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "darkred") +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "red", high = "darkred") +
  facet_wrap(~year)
```

[image]